# Visual Studio Web Site CSS Won't Apply

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2013

I am, for the first time, trying to create a website in VS2013. I created a new website, and set `Home.html` as the startup page. And that works just fine. Then I added a file called `Home.css` to be the stylesheet for `Home.html`. For my HTML I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-div">
        Testing!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.header-div {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The `header-div` class comes up in my IntelliSense and everything, but it won't actually apply to the `div`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you linked to that stylesheet in the head?

Comment: Where is the css linked to your html?

Comment: In your `<head>` tag, include the css like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/csslocation/home.css">`

Comment: Another reason why a plain text editor is better than a full-fledged IDE for beginners.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, that's the point I'm trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should link the css : add this part to head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" />
```

So your code would be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" />
 <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="header-div">
    Testing!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```